# Python: minus 1 from int in function

Tags: python, function, int

How do you minus one from an INT in a function?

This is what I'm trying:

```
try:
    lives
except NameError:
    lives = 6
else:
    lives = lives-1
 print("\nWrong!\nYou have " +str(lives)+ " lives remaining\n")
```

But it doesn't work.

The lives are always at 6 :(

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

```
def main():

    used = []
    print(blanks)
    choice = input("\nEnter a letter:")

            lives -= 1
            print("\nWrong!\nYou have " +str(lives)+ " lives remaining\n")
            used.append(choice)
            main()
```

Comment: how about just :  lives -= 1

Comment: You mention a function, but don't show one in the question. You might have a scope issue if the `print` statement is outside a function but your `try` statement is inside one.

Comment: Integers are immutable; `lives = lives - 1` will reassign the name `lives` in the current scope, but doesn't change the underlying object.

Comment: If I define it in the function it will get overwritten, if I define it outside the function it tells me `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lives' referenced before assignment`

Comment: You should `return` the new value from the function, and reassign the name in the calling scope `lives = some_func(lives)`. Research Python scoping.

Answer (score 2):

The real reason you are seeing 6 is because the **NameError** is thrown, and therefore your else clause is never actually executed

```
NameError: name 'lives' is not defined
```

Comment: Thats the point, If nameError is only thrown once the variable will be assigned once and not again.

Answer (score 0):

If lives wasn't defined before, than `try: lives` will always get you to the except section.
if you define lives before this code (by assigning it something) or inside the try section, you'll get to see the -1 in action.

```
try:
    lives = 1
except NameError:
    lives = 6
else:
    lives = lives-1
print lives
```

will output 0

as well as:

```
lives = 1
try:
    lives
except NameError:
    lives = 6
else:
    lives = lives-1
print lives
```

EDIT:
For your comment, here is some sample code that does something like what you are probably trying to achieve, that is a game of guess the letter. Hopefully this will help you.

```
def main():
    # The setup
    right_answer = "a"
    lives = 6

    # The game
    while lives > 0:
        choice = raw_input("Enter a letter:")
        if choice == right_answer:
            print "yay, you win!"
            break
        else:
            lives -= 1
            print "nay, try again, you have", lives, "lives left"
    else:
        print "you lose"

# This will call our function and run the game
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

** written fro python 2.7, for python 3 the prints will need parentheses.

Comment: If I define it in the function it will get overwritten, if I define it outside the function it tells me UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lives' referenced before assignment

Comment: Indeed it has to be fined in the the function (or the scope you want it), as for overwritting it, that's up to the use you make of it. if you overwrite it it will, if you don't it won't. Assuming you are trying to setup a game with user "lives" as number of times they can loose, you probably want to start by assigning it with the number (for example "lives = 3" and then start subtracting from it.

Comment: sorry, the point is, that in order to subtract from a variable, it needs to be defined and assigned in the scope you want to subtract form it.

Comment: Can you give me the code to do it? I tried looking up scopes and as I'm currently a super beginner and just 14 I feel I learn more when looking at how to do it...

Comment: The code very much depends on what exactly you want to do. and don't worry, the best way to learn these things is to try, get stuck, and look for the different solutions. :)

Comment: All i'm trying to do is set the lives to 6 and minus one if the user guesses wrong. I get it all to work but i'm stuck at the minus one life. All of it is in a function called main

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to go was define the variable outside the function and then put:

`global lives` in the function.

Job done.